# Button only works when tapped twice

Tags: swift, button, segue

I have two buttons that each have a different segue to a different view controller, which is only triggered if certain conditions are met. For some reason, one of the buttons works fine, the other button has to be tapped twice in order for it to segue to the next view controller. The strange part is that the code for both buttons and segue if conditions are copied and pasted and slightly modified to go to their respective vcs. How can I get both buttons to work on the first tap?

So far I've tried:

1. reordering the button functions
2. reordering the segue functions
3. deleting/reconnecting the button
4. deleting/reconnecting the button

I believe it has something to do with the following code because when I remove it, this behavior is gone and a different but similar feature in the app with virtually the same code (minus the part below) works just fine. I do need it however due to testing for nil/errors:

```
override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return nextButton
}
```

Here is the code

```
import UIKit

class bathShowerMeasurementViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

    
}


var nextButton = false

@IBOutlet weak var inchesButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func inches(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var unitError: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var centimeterButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func centimeter(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.isSelected {
        sender.isSelected = false
    } else {
        sender.isSelected = true
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var length: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lenghtError: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var width: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var widthError: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var height: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var heightError: UILabel!


@IBAction func showerCalc(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    let widthTub = Double(width.text!)
    let lengthTub = Double(length.text!)
    let heightTub = Double(height.text!)

    var enableNextButton = true

    if widthTub == nil || widthTub == 0.0 {
        widthError.text = "Enter Width"
        enableNextButton = false
    }
    if heightTub == nil || heightTub == 0.0 {
        heightError.text = "Enter Height"
        enableNextButton = false
    }
    if lengthTub == nil || lengthTub == 0.0 {
        lenghtError.text = "Enter Length"
        enableNextButton = false
    }
    switch (inchesButton.isSelected, centimeterButton.isSelected) {
        case (false, false):
            unitError.text = "Please Select A Unit"
            enableNextButton = false
        case (true, true):
            unitError.text = "Only Select One Unit"
            enableNextButton = false
        default: break
    }
    nextButton = enableNextButton
    
}


@IBAction func goToShower(_ sender: UIButton) {
  
    let widthTub = Double(width.text!)
    let lengthTub = Double(length.text!)
    let heightTub = Double(height.text!)

    var enableNextButton = true

    if widthTub == nil || widthTub == 0.0 {
        widthError.text = "Enter Width"
        enableNextButton = false
    }
    if heightTub == nil || heightTub == 0.0 {
        heightError.text = "Enter Height"
        enableNextButton = false
    }
    if lengthTub == nil || lengthTub == 0.0 {
        lenghtError.text = "Enter Length"
        enableNextButton = false
    }
    switch (inchesButton.isSelected, centimeterButton.isSelected) {
        case (false, false):
            unitError.text = "Please Select A Unit"
            enableNextButton = false
        case (true, true):
            unitError.text = "Only Select One Unit"
            enableNextButton = false
        default: break
    }
    nextButton = enableNextButton
    
}
  

override func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    return nextButton
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let bathLength = Double(length.text!)
    let bathWidth = Double(width.text!)
    let bathHeight = Double(height.text!)
    let water = Double(bathLength! *  bathWidth! * bathHeight!)
    
    if (segue.identifier == "showerCalc") {
        
        if inchesButton.isSelected == true{
        let bathWater = water / 231
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! showerFillMethodViewController
        destinationVC.bathFlow = String(bathWater)
        }
        
        if centimeterButton.isSelected == true{
        let bathWater = water / 3785.41
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! showerFillMethodViewController
        destinationVC.bathFlow = String(bathWater)
                    
            }
           
    }
    
    if (segue.identifier == "showerTool") {
     
       if inchesButton.isSelected == true{
       let bathWater = water / 231
       let destinationVC = segue.destination as! showerFlowMainViewController
           destinationVC.bathFlow = String(bathWater)
           
       }
       
       if centimeterButton.isSelected == true{
       let bathWater = water / 3785.41
           let destinationVC = segue.destination as! showerFlowMainViewController
               destinationVC.bathFlow = String(bathWater)
       
        }
   } 
}
}
```

Comment: Print the value of `nextButton`  in `shouldPerformlSegue` along with the identifier (to be sure). And then, check why it's `false` in the first attempt?

Comment: Hey! This was a great recommendation. I'll have to keep this in mind for future bugs. When I do this, the button that works returns "True Optional ("showerTool"), but the one that doesn't work first comes back as True and then Optional (showerCalc"). The identifiers are correct, but for some reason the order of optional and true are swapped. Any idea what that could mean?

Comment: You need to debug, you can add a `didSet`: `var nextButton = false { didSet { print("Did change value to: \(nextButton))" }}`, and see when it's changed, and why it's not correct. And I don't see why it should be "optional", see it's not an optional value, that's strange.